# It have some error when i run the delete script

Tags: php, html

The error is:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''sarojini'_bookings WHERE date=2014-07-24 AND start=10:00:00' at line 1

```
<?php
      session_start();
    require ('sql_connect.php'); 

     if (isset($_SESSION['id']) && is_numeric($_SESSION['id']))
     {
     $id=$_SESSION['id']; 
    $sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM lecturer WHERE staff_id ='$id'");
    $q = mysql_fetch_array($sql1);
    $n = $q['name'];
    $sql2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE lecturer_name='$n' ORDER BY date");
    $q1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2);
    $d = $q1['date'];
    $s = $q1['start'];

     $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM '$n'_bookings WHERE date=$d AND start=$s")
     or die(mysql_error()); 

      //header("Location: manageappointment1.php");
     }
     else
      {
     //header("Location: manageappointment1.php");
     }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your query : `"DELETE FROM '$n'_bookings WHERE date=$d AND start=$s"`

Correct query : `"DELETE FROM ".$n."_bookings WHERE date=$d AND start=$s"`

In fact the query is correct, it's just about your var ..

You can also write :

`"DELETE FROM {$n}_bookings WHERE date=$d AND start=$s"`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':30:00' at line 1

Comment: mmhh, looks like your date formats are not timestamps (int) so you should use quotes (`'`) like this : `"DELETE FROM {$n}_bookings WHERE date='$d' AND start='$s'"`

Comment: Ah yes, and you script is vulnerable if the attacker can change the ID in the session, use `$id=mysql_real_espace_string($_SESSION['id']);` ( [see manual of the function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) )

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
 $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM '$n'_bookings WHERE date=$d AND start=$s")or die(mysql_error());
```

use

```
 $result = mysql_query("DELETE FROM ".$n."_bookings WHERE date='$d' AND start='$s'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score -2):

I think that is because you use simple quote. Use this :

```
DELETE FROM $n_bookings WHERE date=$d AND start=$s
```

Comment: nop man, $n_bookings will throw an error : undefined variable "n_bookings", here you don't have the choice, you have to use `"text{$var}text"` or `"text".$var."text"`